# TypeError: can't access property "constructor", object is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, authentication, next.js

I created this class using nextJS.

```
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup } from 'firebase/auth';
import { google} from './providers';

export default class Auth {
    constructor() {
        this.auth = getAuth();
    }

    static instance = new Auth();

    signInWithGoogle = async () => {
        try {
            return await signInWithPopup(this.auth, google)
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            throw new Error(err);
        }
    }

    static currentUser() {
        return this.auth.currentUser;
    }
}
```

And in the browsers console I received this error
`TypeError: can't access property "constructor", object is undefined`

I want to create a class for authentication of my app with firebase.

Comment: `static instance = new Auth();` does not make sense. You should not be creating an instance of the class in the class.

Comment: yes, you can, I use it very often in my projects